# MS SQL Server - atomizing operations with transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions

My asp.net WEB API application process requests. Each request can make multiple calls to DB.
Same user can call a request from different IP addresses.

I need to develop wait chain for requests for the users, so the same user request will wait previous request to be completed.

Previously i made it by running request in a transaction scope: 
Isolation level = ReadCommited
First request to DB update user row record in order to lock the row, so other request should wait here while previous transaction running.

After i made a load test with multiple different users, not same in the same time, i figured out that they somehow dealocking eachother:

*Transaction (Process ID 119) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.*

My question is: what would be best approach in my situation to develop a user level wait-chain for app requests?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to abandon your approach. Instead you should simply fix the bug (the deadlock). On the other hand using database locks as a queue is not exactly scalable. How many queued requests will there be at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking `I need to develop wait chain for requests`, why don't you make the chain? You can receive all requests, store them in any queue (or in DB), and then process them one by one.

To achieve thi with transactions you must be very careful and follow several rules to [minimize deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242(v=sql.105).aspx):

- access objects in the same order
- keep transactions short
- use bound connection

Som revise your code, manipulating with DB.

Comment: It's an option too. But i want to know if there is a good approach to achieve my goal with sql transactions.